# IE7 (ugg), and Layout Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, Respond.js for anything under IE9

Why is my page doing this in IE7?
http://www.ctautobodyshops.com/

Screenshot:

[image]
Let me know what else you need...

Comment: @connor How'd you do that?  I was looking for a way to do it, but couldn't figure it out...

Comment: When writing the question there is an image button above the text field and to the right of these {}

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 does not support IE 7, it supports IE 8 with Respond.js. However IE8 has support for certain CSS properties that IE7 does not handle. The  main one that works with the entire Bootstrap system is

> box-sizing: border-box

There's an IE7 css and a polyfill for Bootstrap here: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

But even with those things, if you use in your own custom css styles that are not supported by IE7 then they will not show up styled as on modern browsers.

There's other classes like inline-block that don't work with IE 7 either, so in your own CSS you need to use fallbacks.

Answer (score 1):

`<section class="row">` has `height:100%` which doesn't work nicely with IE7. You have to give `width` in IE7.

If you remove the `height: 100%` it helps and then add `width` atleast in percentage to each required `element`